# Nested curly brackets {{ }} in WPF/XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, markup

What is the meaning of nested curly brackets in attribute values in WPF/XAML markup? As in the following example:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource pictures}}">
```

Comment: Why couldn't it just be 

    `<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource pictures}">` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That binds the `ItemsSource` of the list box to a `StaticResource` called `pictures`. It's simply nesting one markup extension in another.

Read about markup extensions in XAML here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could not the same effect be achieved using the following simplified notation: <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource pictures}">

Comment: No, when you data bind to an `ItemsSource` you need to specify a `Binding` object, so you have to use `{Binding Source=...}`.

Comment: @BoltClock: A binding is **not** required.  Any dependency property can have a ordinary assigned value.  Since `Source` is fixed and `Path` defaults to `.`, Andrew's proposed simplification is indeed identical in this case.  This would not be true if a non-default `Path` were specified.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting of multiple markup extensions is supported by WPF, and each markup extension will be evaluated deepest first.

```
 <Setter Property="Background"
Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
```

In this usage, the x:Static statement is evaluated first and returns a string. That string is then used as the argument for DynamicResource.

so here

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource pictures}}">
```

it will assign the pictures (may be collection) to the itemsource of the listbox

please have look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx#Nesting